# Cannot display edit form when clicked on edit button and the form doesn't parse error and displays blank page

Tags: php

**EDIT**: My edit button refuse to work.

I'm trying to edit this page, but it seems to be breaking when I click the edit button. it is retrieving data from the database and displaying on faculty.php successfully while if I try to edit it shows a blank page. what is wrong with my code, please.

**faculty.php:** a separate page where i have my edit button

```
     <td>
       <form action="facultyedit.php" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
         <button type="submit" name="edit_data_btn" class="btn btn-success">EDIT</button>   
       </form>
     </td>
```

**facultyedit page:** where i receive the edit button

```
    <?php
        
        if (isset($_POST['edit_data_btn'])) 
        {
      
            $id = $_POST['edit_id'];

            $query = " SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$id' ";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            

        foreach ($query_run as $row ) {
   
      ?>

    <form action="" method="POST" >

        <input type="text" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="edit_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Designation:</label>
          <input type="text" name="edit_designation" value="<?php echo $row['design']; ?>" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description:</label>
          <input type="text" name="edit_description" value="<?php echo $row['descrip']; ?>" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Upload Image:</label>
          <input type="file" name="edit_faculty_image" id="faculty_image" value="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="form-control" >
        </div> 

        <div class="">
          <a href="faculty.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>

          <button type="update" name="update_aboutusbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

        </div>

    </form>

<?php
            }
        }
    ?
```

> 

Comment: Where are you making the database connection? And what made you think you could just foreach over the result of `mysqli_query`?

Comment: On facultyedit.php page

Comment: @ CBroe So what is your advise?

Comment: That you go and read up on how to properly loop over the result of a MySQLi query in a beginner tutorial.

Comment: I tried **mysqli_fetch_array($result)** it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

**I have fixed the issue:**

The problem was that I was selecting a register table from the database instead of the faculty table.